# Can i access html element Id from any from anyfiles?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner to Java-script.

i have a concern

```
on mainPage.html 
<div id="showDialog" style="display:none"> </div>
```

on mainPage.js

```
 $('#ShowDialog').load("../xxxx.html", function (content) {
xxxxxxxxxxx
     });
```

It is easy understand that if you want to use the id element you just call #element

So, my question is here:

if you are in Setup.js  (setup.html has no id attribute like #ShowDialog)

can you still call （So, it will do something on mainPage.html ??  ）

```
 $('#ShowDialog').load("../xxxx.html", function (content) {
xxxxxxxxxxx
     });
```

If so, is the class also do the same job? i know id is unique and class is common. So, if one file class can be accessed from other file?

like

$('.ShowDialog').load("../xxxx.html", function (content) {
    xxxxxxxxxxx
         });

By the way, why we call class using $(.'ShowDialog')rather than just call name like   $('ShowDialog')

for class="ShowDialog"

Comment: Just text like `'ShowDialog'` would try to match an element, ie `<ShowDialog>` and not a css class which is represented by a preceding dot `.`

Comment: I believe it is accurate to say that if `$(selector)` does not find any elements, then the `load()` would be skipped. Edit: checked the source.  This is accurate.

Comment: Learn about jQuery Selectors. Their documentation explains the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reference an html Element from an external Javascript file it could be as follows:

myHtml.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- First Import Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <!-- Then the module you wish to work with-->
    <script src="./ReferencebyId.js"></script>


    <title>referencing html Element by Id</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- the Id you will reference on the module -->
    <p id="myId">Change this text</p>
    <button onclick="changeInnerHtml()">Change paragraph text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

ReferencebyId.js

```
function changeInnerHtml(){
  //This is how you would reference the Id, with '#' character
  $("#myId").text("changed from external js file referencing Id");
}
```

Remember that if you wish to use the class to reference the Html Element, you have to make sure only that element has that class, or if you wish to affect more than one element you can put them the same class, and reference them as `$(".nameOfClass")`